# Piping in dplyr - how can I combine data

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to understand piping with dplyr. The Example ist with the `presidential` dataset from `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data("presidential")
presidential %>%
  select(name,start,end,party) %>%
  mutate(time = end - start) %>%
  group_by(party) %>%
  mutate(time_per_party = length(time)) -> x
x
```

So I calculate the time of each president, that's working. Now I want to summ the time each party was presidential but instead I get the amount of presidents they have.

```
         name      start        end      party      time time_per_party
        (chr)     (date)     (date)      (chr)    (dfft)          (int)
1  Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican 2922 days              6
2     Kennedy 1961-01-20 1963-11-22 Democratic 1036 days              4
3      Johson 1963-11-22 1969-01-20 Democratic 1886 days              4
4       Nixon 1969-01-20 1974-08-09 Republican 2027 days              6
5        Ford 1974-08-09 1977-01-20 Republican  895 days              6
6      Carter 1977-01-20 1981-01-20 Democratic 1461 days              4
7      Reagan 1981-01-20 1989-01-20 Republican 2922 days              6
8        Bush 1989-01-20 1993-01-20 Republican 1461 days              6
9     Clinton 1993-01-20 2001-01-20 Democratic 2922 days              4
10       Bush 2001-01-20 2009-01-20 Republican 2922 days              6
```

Any Idea how to do that?
The Result at the end should be something like that:

```
party        days
Republican   xxx
Democratic   xxx
```

Comment: `presidential %>% mutate(days = difftime(end, start)) %>% group_by(party) %>% summarise(days = sum(days)) %>% ungroup()` should do what you want.

Comment: thx @Z.Lin , what's the **%>% ungroup()** for at the end?

Comment: `ungroup()` removes all the grouping. I like to do that because in more complex use cases, I often group by multiple variables, and unintended [peeling off](http://opiateforthemass.es/articles/groupby_summarize/) behaviour can result. So I'd rather make a habit of ungrouping explicitly to know where I am at each point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a sollution very simmilar to Z.Lin's comment:

```
presidential %>%  mutate(time = end - start) %>% group_by(party) %>%  summarise(days = sum(time))
```

do's the trick

Answer (score 1):

try

```
presidential %>%  mutate(time = end - start) %>% group_by(party) %>%  summarise(days = sum(time))
```